# bazel sync asks for github login and fails

Tags: github, bazel

I don't know if this is because I had to change my github password today, or if it's related to github switching to the use of tokens instead of passwords for access.

I had been using `local_repository` for dependencies between my various projects as a lot of them were in flux as I migrated to bazel, and it didn't make sense to have to constantly push to github and then resync for each incremental change.

Today I was finally ready to start switching back to using `git_repository` for the dependencies.

Separately from this, I found I couldn't log in to github on the web and ended up resetting my password (I suspect I had accidentally mucked something up in my password manager).

Anyway, I was able to get the first projects changes all committed and pushed to github with no problem.  When I went to the 2nd project, I changed the dependency on project #1 from a `local_repository` to a `git_repository` and tried `bazel sync` to pick up the changes I'd just committed there.

The result: a login window for github popped up and I tried the login credentials that I'd just successfully used to log in on the web.  The box disappeared and reappeared, and when I tried the same creds again I got the error below.

I had used the same command in the past and everything worked.  I don't know if the password change is the issue and the old one is stuck somewhere or if github's switch to requiring tokens is the issue.  I found [this link](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk) about using github tokens with bazelisk abnd tried setting an environment variable for `BAZELISK_GITHUB_TOKEN` to a newly reated token, but this did not help. I'm not sure where to go from here.

The error:

```
C:\projects\java\common>bazel sync
INFO: Repository bdl_deps instantiated at:
  C:/projects/java/common/WORKSPACE:5:15: in <toplevel>
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:199:33: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'bdl_deps':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 181, column 30, in _git_repository_implementation
                update = _clone_or_update(ctx)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 36, column 20, in _clone_or_update
                git_ = git_repo(ctx, directory)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 91, column 12, in git_repo
                _update(ctx, git_repo)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 103, column 10, in _update
                fetch(ctx, git_repo)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 145, column 15, in fetch
                _error(ctx.name, ["git"] + args, st.stderr)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 190, column 9, in _error
                fail("error running '%s' while working with @%s:\n%s" % (command_text, name, stderr))
Error in fail: error running 'git fetch origin master:origin/master' while working with @bdl_deps:
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error
ERROR: Error fetching repository: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 181, column 30, in _git_repository_implementation
                update = _clone_or_update(ctx)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 36, column 20, in _clone_or_update
                git_ = git_repo(ctx, directory)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 91, column 12, in git_repo
                _update(ctx, git_repo)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 103, column 10, in _update
                fetch(ctx, git_repo)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 145, column 15, in fetch
                _error(ctx.name, ["git"] + args, st.stderr)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 190, column 9, in _error
                fail("error running '%s' while working with @%s:\n%s" % (command_text, name, stderr))
Error in fail: error running 'git fetch origin master:origin/master' while working with @bdl_deps:
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error
ERROR: no such package '@bdl_deps//': error running 'git fetch origin master:origin/master' while working with @bdl_deps:
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error
Loading: loading...

C:\projects\java\common>bazel version
Bazelisk version: v1.3.0
Build label: 4.1.0
Build target: bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri May 21 11:17:01 2021 (1621595821)
Build timestamp: 1621595821
Build timestamp as int: 1621595821

C:\projects\java\common>clear

C:\projects\java\common>bazel sync
INFO: Repository bdl_deps instantiated at:
  C:/projects/java/common/WORKSPACE:5:15: in <toplevel>
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:199:33: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'bdl_deps':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 181, column 30, in _git_repository_implementation
                update = _clone_or_update(ctx)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 36, column 20, in _clone_or_update
                git_ = git_repo(ctx, directory)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 91, column 12, in git_repo
                _update(ctx, git_repo)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 103, column 10, in _update
                fetch(ctx, git_repo)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 145, column 15, in fetch
                _error(ctx.name, ["git"] + args, st.stderr)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 190, column 9, in _error
                fail("error running '%s' while working with @%s:\n%s" % (command_text, name, stderr))
Error in fail: error running 'git fetch origin master:origin/master' while working with @bdl_deps:
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error
ERROR: Error fetching repository: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 181, column 30, in _git_repository_implementation
                update = _clone_or_update(ctx)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl", line 36, column 20, in _clone_or_update
                git_ = git_repo(ctx, directory)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 91, column 12, in git_repo
                _update(ctx, git_repo)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 103, column 10, in _update
                fetch(ctx, git_repo)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 145, column 15, in fetch
                _error(ctx.name, ["git"] + args, st.stderr)
        File "C:/_bazel_out/seszwrcl/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl", line 190, column 9, in _error
                fail("error running '%s' while working with @%s:\n%s" % (command_text, name, stderr))
Error in fail: error running 'git fetch origin master:origin/master' while working with @bdl_deps:
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error
ERROR: no such package '@bdl_deps//': error running 'git fetch origin master:origin/master' while working with @bdl_deps:
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error
Loading: loading...
```

Further info:

```
C:\projects\java\common>bazel version
Bazelisk version: v1.3.0
Build label: 4.1.0
Build target: bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri May 21 11:17:01 2021 (1621595821)
Build timestamp: 1621595821
Build timestamp as int: 1621595821
```

OS: Windows 10.

Comment: Looking around https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/4.1.0/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl it should just call `git` it finds with corresponding arguments -> any authentication configuration / helper you use for that `git` needs to be enable it to `fetch` (bazel or not) from the repo(s). Perhaps check this is still the case / workin (after the password update) and adjust if necessary? Generally, it may be easier to debug just taking bazel out of the equation for a bit.

Comment: After trying some more things, I ended up regenerating my token for the command line and tried again.  Still no luck.

Then I tried just running `git clone` and that still gave me the popup, which did not work either, but instead of failing it then prompted me for username and password from the command line.  Using the token for the password it seemed to work.  I deleted and tried again just to confirm and this time I got an HttpRequestException at first, then it proceeded to work.

And suddenty, `bazel sync` works too.